# How to apply unsupervised classification to spatial data

Tags: clustering, spatial, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to learn how to apply unsupervised classification to spatial data.
In near infra red satelite pictures; the ocean is dark and the forest is white.
Each pixel in such an image is an observation. I guess the variables are [x-position, y-position, grayscale]?

Which methods could I use to classify the pixels into ocean and forest?
I want to ensure that the points in the classes forms spatially connected regions (e.g. no single trees in the ocean).

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds to me like an image processing question, unless you are looking for a very complex structure. 
You may want to use a gaussian filter on the image, and then apply a threshold.
Also, you can ask in https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

This software (it won the best demonstration award at SSTD 2011) [Link](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-22922-0_41) should be able to do spatial clustering, too.